# Recalculate formula field in unit test code

Tags: apex, formula, error, vlocity

While trying to recalculate a formula field "cross-object" i came across this weird error.

Code to reproduce:

```java
Product2 product = new Product2(
    ProductCode = 'CODE1',
    // vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeName__c field points to `vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeId__r.Name`
    vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeId__c = 'a3E000000000001EAA',
    vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeId__r = new vlocity_cmt__ObjectClass__c(
        Id = 'a3E000000000001EAA',
        Name = 'My Spec Name'
    )
);


System.debug(product.vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeName__c); // -> null
product.recalculateFormulas();
System.debug(product.vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeName__c); // -> null


List<FormulaRecalcResult> results = Formula.recalculateFormulas(new List<SObject>{
    product
});

System.debug(results);
```

The error this produces:

```
13:37:43.27 (29343897)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|DEBUG|null
13:37:43.27 (30540336)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
13:37:43.27 (41512272)|USER_DEBUG|[21]|DEBUG|(FormulaRecalcResult:[recalcFieldErrors=(FormulaRecalcFieldError:[fieldError=Field not supported: vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeId__r. If this is lookup field, try setting the ID field instead., fieldName=vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeId__r], FormulaRecalcFieldError:[fieldError=ORA-20001:
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CACCESS", line 3305
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.COLDACCESSCUST", line 53
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CACCESS", line 3253
ORA-06512: at "BASHFUL.CACCESS", line 2959
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQLException while executing plsql statement: 
{call cAccess.check_entity_access_proc_ncu(?,?,?,?,?,?)}
(EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED, a3E000000000001, EXCLUDED, true, false), 
fieldName=ObjectTypeName]), 
record=Product2:{ProductCode=CODE1, vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeId__c=a3E000000000001EAA, vlocity_cmt__ObjectTypeName__c=null, vlocity_cmt__ParentClassCode__c=null, vlocity_cmt__ProductSpecName__c=null}])
```

I know the `SObject.recalculateFormulas()` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_recalculateFormulas) doesn't work for cross-object, but I am wondering, does this also apply to the `Formula.recalculateFormulas()` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Formula.htm#apex_System_Formula_recalculateFormulas) method?

Comment: I'm going to ask around, see what pops up. I'm guessing that cross-object formulas aren't supported, based on the error, but you shouldn't be seeing a ORA-* error code. This likely needs to be logged as a bug with R&D.

Comment: @sfdcfox did you find any related information? Or did you register a bug with R&D?